# issue editing Access database table with OpenRecordSet

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am very new to access. I am trying to update a table using OpenRecordSet and am having issues.
Here is my code:

```
Set rst2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_Inventory", dbOpenTable)
With rst2
.Edit
If !InventoryID = Me.InventoryID Then

!Stock = Me.Quantity
.Update
.Close
End If
End With
Set rst2 = Nothing
```

This is called when an update button is clicked on an Inventory Form page. There is an update button and an input box, "Quantity" for every row on the form. Here is my issue:

1) When I click the update button, ALL of the Quantity input boxes (for each item) is changed to that new number. How do I specify just that line?

2) When I click update on the FIRST row, ID=1, and look back at the inventory form, I see that the changes have been made to the Stock column. But when I click the other rows, there is no change. I have a feeling that these stem from one underlining issue.

Comment: Is tbl_inventory the underlying recordset of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no rs.MoveNext line in your code.  Try this:

```
Set rst2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_Inventory", dbOpenTable)

Do While rst2.eof = false

With rst2
If !InventoryID = Me.InventoryID Then
   .Edit
   !Stock = Me.Quantity
   .Update
End If

End With

rst2.MoveNext

Loop
rst2.close
Set rst2 = Nothing
```

Comment: Now I get the runtime error - '3420' , Object invalid or no longer set

Comment: Can you put a break point in the code, step through it (using F8) and tell me which line it's happening on?
    EDIT: I changed the code above slightly which may fix it, I believe the recordset was being closed in the middle of the loop.  Paste the new code in first and if it still gives you an error then please let me know which line it happens on.

Comment: Its happening on the rst2.MoveNext line

Comment: See my edited code above.  The recordset was getting closed too soon.  I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The inventory is properly being edit now. But there is still one more glitch: when I click update on one of the rows, all of the 'Quantity' input boxes on the form get that new number, it just doesn't get changed in the actual table. Why is that?

Comment: Is it a Continuous Form?  I don't really understand the layout and how the Quantity box is supposed to react.

Comment: It is a continuous form. The form layout looks as follows: A bunch of rows showing item name, amount in stock, and then an update button with a user input box which you enter the new number and click update. So, for every row in the table the form creates a new update button which is supposed to update that entry in the table.

Comment: Me.Quantity would then be the textbox name for every record.  So, if you're updating Me.Quantity, it's going to put that same value in the textbox on every record.  What you probably want to do is use a Me.Requery or Me.RecordSource.Refresh or something along those lines, which will then reload all the data in the form with the new values.

Comment: Never knew about those, will look into them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How are you selecting a single record to change?  Have you tried using the .FindFirst?

So after `With` put:

```
.FindFirst ("[InventoryID] = '" & Me.InventoryID & "'")
```

That will make sure you are only using that one record.

Comment: Right after the with, keeping everything else the same? I tried that and got an error - run time error 3251, operation not supported for this type of object.